# (class) does not name a type

Tags: c++, types, include, g++

I'm trying to compile a program through makefile. When I launch make from the command line the compiler gives me this error:

```
g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp -std=c++11
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
athlete.h:9:9: error: 'string' does not name a type
      string name;
```

I've already tried to search and I've found that some common issues were related to missing `#include <string>`, "inverted preprocessor directives", bad use of `using namespace std;` or bad use of `#includes` within other headers file. I've tried to fix looking at these 4 points, but without results, maybe I'm overlooking something. Hoping this question will not bore you. Thanks. Below some blocks of files' code (*not all files are included*).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "athlete.h"
#include "upd_at.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Athlete f;
    f.set_generalities();
    f.set_perfind();
    f = update_test_res(f);

    return 0;
}
```

**athlete.h**

**"...."** means: (hopefully) not relevant lines of code.

```
#ifndef ATHLETE_H_INCLUDED
#define ATHLETE_H_INCLUDED


//declarations of Athlete
class Athlete{
private:
    //generalities
        string name;
        int age;
        int height;
        double weight;
        int tr_exp;
        ....
public:
        ....
};
#endif // ATHLETE_H_INCLUDED
```

**athlete.cpp**

```
void Athlete::set_generalities(){
    string in_name;
    int in_age;
    int in_height;
    double in_weight;
    int in_tr_exp;
    ....
}
void Athlete::set_perfind(){
    int in_RHR, in_maxHR;
    double in_1rmsq, in_1rmbp, in_1rmcl, in_1rmdl, hndgrp;
    ....
    return ;
}
//create a first txt with athlete generalities and tests column
void create_ath_file(){
// current time/date based on current system
     time_t now = time(0);
     tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
     const char* name_pt = name.c_str();
     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open(name_pt);
     ....
     myfile.close();
}
```

**makefile**

```
p1: main.o upd_athlete.o athlete.o
    g++ -Wall -g main.o upd_athlete.o athlete.o -o p1 -std=c++11

main.o: main.cpp athlete.h athlete.cpp upd_at.h upd_athlete.cpp
    g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp -std=c++11

upd_athlete.o: upd_athlete.cpp upd_at.h athlete.cpp athlete.h
    g++ -Wall -g -c upd_athlete.cpp -std=c++11

athlete.o: athlete.cpp athlete.h
    g++ -Wall -g -c athlete.cpp -std=c++11

clean:
    \rm *.o
```

Answer (score 4):

You need either to:

- <s>use `using namespace std;` in `athlete.h`</s>
- <s>move `using namespace std;` in `main.cpp` before `#include "athlete.h"`</s>

<sup>Now these are just very bad hacks.</sup>

- to qualify `string` - `std::string name` in the `athlete.h`. `std::` is not that hard to type while we're at it, so I wouldn't use `using namespace std;` anywhere.

Also, you should `#include` the appropriate standard headers directly to the `athlete.h`, otherwise you're just relying that the user and `athlete.cpp` does so before `athlete.h` inclusion.

Comment: Let me know if I understood: A) delete 'using namespace std;' B) add 'std::' just in the header file. C) What do you mean with standard headers? Ones I use in main.cpp? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You'll get tons of `'string' does not name a type`-like errors after removing **all occurences of `using namespace std;`**, and you'll fix them by prepending `std::`. Yes, those you have in `main.cpp` are standard C++ headers (apart from `*.h` ones, those are C and C++ uses `c*` naming). Also, you should ask yourself if you need every one of them. There's a lot of `#include`s.

Comment: Thanks it seems have worked. But anyway I can't finish to compile. Now the problem is: 'Athlete' does not name a type. Should I include athlete.h (header which defines class Athlete) everywhere I need this class or there is a solution like std:: ?

Comment: Yes, you forgot some `#include` directive. And no, this error has nothing to do with namespaces, and not at all with `std`.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::string instead of string.

Comment: You look a little young to be on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Its my childhood pic. I am already Engineer doing job in software programming.